# When are tensor products preferable to s smooths in GAM(M)s?

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, splines, smoothing

I learned in this forum and from a book of Simon Wood, that tensor products rather than thin-plate (s) smooths are used when covariates are not naturally on the same scale. However in my experience tensor products fit the raw data much worse. Although tensor products tend to come at a lower cost (lower edf), I have also seen cases where the edf was even slightly higher, but the fit appeared to be worse.
Here, I try to compare the fits of t2 (tensor product) and s smooths when data are not naturally on the same scale. The s smooths I fit both on scaled data and data that is left on the original scale.

```
  my_data <- structure(list(response = c(2.39425228151987, 1.39128190263093, 
    2.50428161074068, 3.86472173231013, -0.916290731874155, 2.55489902160804, 
    2.82672173081971, 1.68550232742944, 1.49477563291396, 1.72988406550997, 
    2.02683159140754, 1.14103300455206, 1.87487437593856, 2.49072303510944, 
    3.0521126069901, 4.07158757509948, 2.27726728500976, 0.984524711568027, 
    2.22786154679811, 0.356807410035416, 1.94039403235045, 2.40784560365154, 
    2.93066027681028, 3.11129061418826, 1.11185751541813, 1.89160480419777, 
    2.76443053453832, 1.67436451771027, 1.4655675420144, 0.420135436312198, 
    2.80819714970715, 1.51072193949494, 2.63404478779171, 2.90306858869057, 
    0.60431596685333, 2.33214389523559, 2.67896462020711, 2.90197089373952, 
    2.77196352684586, 3.00667221359233, 3.03189475390811, 2.69056488676119, 
    0.569946862225576, 1.31103187661934, 3.13217574841469, 1.45395300959371, 
    1.19694818938897, 2.24601474150565, 0.897174513655268, 3.02819946369149, 
    1.99877363861238, 2.44347158328805, 0.267688139066169, 2.42037401346055, 
    3.44495377655285, 2.08567209143047, 3.04166120544239, 2.34468626901268, 
    3.36210999295411, 1.93730177451871, 0.920282753143693, 3.89467336709303, 
    3.01936172691415, 1.47672906142919, 2.72075276615151, 1.52717510235689, 
    3.01825836425626, 3.72785975375482, 0.81375908893732, 0.27002713721306, 
    1.86697563615429, 3.10772077550204, 2.77321352700862, 1.15134680344581, 
    0.693147180559945, 2.59955895682882, 1.31372366828506, 2.75302356674494, 
    3.11617842662986, 4.07668962698338, 2.2513854745515, 0.550835359360404, 
    1.85785927093258, 2.9704144655697, 1.92716410623426, 1.61740608208328, 
    2.66587216649973, 2.22354188565359, 1.78507048107726, 2.42921774392741, 
    2.62321826558551, 2.69530262827971, 0.683096844706444, 1.01160091167848, 
    1.28370777234479, 2.19972715351647, 2.15871472257434, 0.741937344729377, 
    1.05416380843312, 3.03783344957263), day_of_year = c(165.390016903749, 
    174.242623751914, 254.140593661938, 216.719959399779, 180.918881309152, 
    197.864474461415, 247.494837570993, 226.585110509597, 86.2198100333203, 
    192.616551622938, 93.0914546600555, 193.206471088542, 133.72762825074, 
    206.8983240305, 194.484408144938, 217.806089696884, 185.654192405355, 
    172.828357413351, 111.393980945717, 245.098249955331, 225.168834580961, 
    185.544803317895, 112.00243681339, 286.123426724967, 166.407671582013, 
    96.908493734004, 162.854300276662, 166.028430495141, 88.2050765381369, 
    179.737641728781, 185.654192405355, 82.0704505481588, 288.305654696156, 
    210.812687187416, 158.743008620181, 96.908493734004, 192.066440150977, 
    233.316680665849, 160.407627673047, 277.219829108916, 296.281403767258, 
    112.00243681339, 184.307776505215, 178.004816292601, 204.077701476743, 
    75.3601848100072, 131.15758371265, 83.086634582441, 63.5729980334962, 
    236.612512186526, 196.882520788419, 97.4592029098683, 171.737595714347, 
    129.688091174753, 216.710636970783, 244.232096789182, 268.848562486188, 
    154.640274016945, 218.768968404316, 146.303711933999, 174.242623751914, 
    217.806089696884, 287.324557152867, 97.4592029098683, 129.688091174753, 
    226.585110509597, 200.815359598473, 206.451428900377, 96.4352558030665, 
    62.9226345057666, 184.307776505215, 210.815946792916, 265.870473591743, 
    180.582585679553, 158.743008620181, 210.765650997869, 115.265297815627, 
    117.992443207322, 137.157651589883, 206.386876637862, 276.495631136483, 
    134.146951381619, 114.979627464336, 211.921636878162, 265.950112696149, 
    115.265297815627, 234.285946424115, 101.008924630473, 171.955202400177, 
    111.393980945717, 307.667092031919, 286.123426724967, 166.407671582013, 
    78.0505750751239, 133.72762825074, 200.815359598473, 184.278552615331, 
    100.067043929044, 86.2198100333203, 221.725250913116), landscape = c(15.33, 
    6.96, 0, 1.48, 0, 0.09, 0, 4.35, 2.14, 0, 1.48, 2.72, 1.94, 1.89, 
    0, 15.33, 4.61, 3.6, 1.89, 2.76, 3.6, 0.74, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0.07, 
    2.14, 0, 3.17, 5.34, 0, 1.48, 0.51, 0, 2.72, 0, 0, 6.33, 6.33, 
    4.35, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.54, 0.74, 1.11, 0, 0.44, 6.94, 0.09, 2.11, 
    2.14, 0.09, 0.07, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.51, 0, 2.76, 6.36, 6.36, 13.24, 
    13.24, 0.15, 0, 0, 0, 0.09, 0.15, 0, 15.82, 2.11, 1.11, 1.92, 
    6.94, 6.13, 23.16, 4.35, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 12.88, 12.31, 1.94, 0, 
    0.09, 1.94, 0.09, 4.61, 0, 0, 0.25, 8.64, 23.16, 5.34)), .Names = c("response", 
    "day_of_year", "landscape"), row.names = c(605L, 2068L, 2766L, 
    858L, 316L, 2113L, 1591L, 2433L, 2880L, 333L, 823L, 1475L, 958L, 
    1681L, 789L, 607L, 1164L, 2665L, 1665L, 2526L, 2669L, 2160L, 
    634L, 677L, 420L, 1437L, 1309L, 2890L, 425L, 2855L, 1329L, 178L, 
    822L, 93L, 44L, 1454L, 1775L, 1783L, 1186L, 1183L, 2431L, 701L, 
    2461L, 1588L, 2763L, 1635L, 2260L, 204L, 2358L, 1879L, 1142L, 
    3005L, 2735L, 2894L, 3016L, 1130L, 757L, 763L, 583L, 404L, 1846L, 
    514L, 2562L, 2924L, 2915L, 2635L, 2623L, 465L, 2745L, 2439L, 
    2445L, 2115L, 461L, 2976L, 67L, 2705L, 115L, 2060L, 1304L, 923L, 
    2761L, 2420L, 620L, 269L, 1380L, 147L, 2847L, 2296L, 950L, 1792L, 
    2088L, 984L, 549L, 1161L, 944L, 2386L, 686L, 1827L, 2934L, 1331L
    ), class = "data.frame")
```

Code:

```
  library(ggplot2)
    library(scales)
    library(grDevices)
    library(gamm4)
    # plot raw data
    colorfunc = colorRampPalette(c("red","white", "blue"))
    ggplot(my_df) +
      geom_smooth(aes(x = day_of_year, y = response))+
      geom_point(aes(x = day_of_year, y = response, color = landscape))+
      scale_colour_gradientn(colors = colorfunc(10))

    ggplot(my_df) +
      geom_smooth(aes(x = landscape, y = response))+
      geom_point(aes(x = landscape, y = response, color = day_of_year))+
      scale_colour_gradientn(colors = colorfunc(10))
    # Scale data
    my_df$day_of_year_scaled = as.numeric(scale(my_df$day_of_year))
    my_df$landscape_scaled   = as.numeric(scale(my_df$landscape))

    # Fit models
    model_t2 = gamm4(response ~ t2(day_of_year, landscape), data = my_df)
    summary(model_t2$gam) # edf = 3
    model_s  = gamm4(response ~ s(day_of_year, landscape), data = my_df)
    summary(model_s$gam) # edf = 11.55 
    model_scaled = gamm4(response ~ s(day_of_year_scaled, landscape_scaled), data = my_df)
    summary(model_s$gam) # edf = 11.55 
    # Predict (obtain estimates)
    my_df$response_t2 = predict(model_t2$gam)
    my_df$response_s  = predict(model_s$gam)
    my_df$response_scaled = predict(model_scaled$gam)
    # Plot raw data and estimates
    ggplot(my_df) +
      geom_smooth(aes(x = day_of_year, y = response), color = "blue", se = F)+
      geom_point(aes(x = day_of_year, y = response), color = "blue")+
      geom_smooth(aes(x = day_of_year, y = response_t2), color = "green", se = F)+
      # geom_point(aes(x = day_of_year, y = response_t2), color = "green")+
      geom_smooth(aes(x = day_of_year, y = response_s), color = "red", se = F)+
      # geom_point(aes(x = day_of_year, y = response_s), color = "red")+
      geom_smooth(aes(x = day_of_year, y = response_scaled), color = "purple", se = F)#+
      # geom_point(aes(x = day_of_year, y = response_scaled), color = "purple")
    ggplot(my_df) +
      geom_smooth(aes(x = landscape, y = response), color = "blue", se = F)+
      geom_point(aes(x = landscape, y = response), color = "blue")+
      geom_smooth(aes(x = landscape, y = response_t2), color = "green", se = F)+
      # geom_point(aes(x = landscape, y = response_t2), color = "green")+
      geom_smooth(aes(x = landscape, y = response_s), color = "red", se = F)+
      # geom_point(aes(x = landscape, y = response_s), color = "red")+
      geom_smooth(aes(x = landscape, y = response_scaled), color = "purple", se = F)#+
    # geom_point(aes(x = landscape, y = response_scaled), color = "purple")
```

Example plot: Fits against time
[image: Response vs time (subset)]

**Q1: Why does the tensor product seem to fit the data less well than the s smooths?**

**Q2: Is it appropriate to scale the data before fitting it with an s smooth?**

**Q3: When is a tensor product superior to an s smooth with scaled covariates?**

PS: Here you see the plot with all my data (not only the subset that I copied here). The models are the same except that they include nested random effects. The t2 smooth doesnt capture the depression in the middle of the year and it peaks later then the raw data and other smooths (but uses also considerably less edf: 8.472 vs 22.4). (All models with the random effects (day_of_year|year/field/block) produced a warning:

> Warning message: In optwrap(optimizer, devfun, getStart(start,
>   rho$lower, rho$pp),  :   convergence code 1 from bobyqa: bobyqa --
>   maximum number of function evaluations exceeded

[image: all data: response vs time]

Comment: It's impossible to read your plots because you haven't provided a key to determine which curve corresponds to which model. True, we could parse your code and figure it out.  But maybe this is one of the reasons nobody has replied or commented on this question... .